# Post-song Terminology

Tags: terminology, lyrics, music, songs

Sometimes, after the actual song is finished, musicians add an extra something to it, not necessarily part of the lyrics. Sometimes they recite a poem or sing lyrics from another song without instrumentals. Sometimes, usually after the last song in an album, there is a long pause and then some messing around or a bonus song obviously not meant to be a part of the album.

Is there a term or terms for the stuff that goes on after a song is finished?

Answer (score 1):

In modern times, I think this would referred to in radio broadcast or musical compositions as an "outro" even when lacking an "intro"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conclusion_(music)

Answer (score 0):

I think the term you are looking for is ***[coda](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/coda)***:

> - (Music) a more or less independent passage, at the end of a composition, introduced to bring it to a satisfactory close.

Dictionary.com

> - [Coda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coda_(music)) [ˈkoːda] (Italian for "tail", plural code) is a term used in music primarily to designate a passage that brings a piece (or a movement) to an end. Technically, it is an expanded cadence. It may be as simple as a few measures, or as complex as an entire section.

Wikipedia

Comment: That's for something within a song. The OP is referring to a term for something outside a song, or even a *collection* of songs.